# How to click on a <li> <a/> </li> button in Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to click on a button like this using Pure javascript:

```
<ul>
<li class="inactive-link"><a href="/appointment?q=q8345lbf3r9tcmgMnfsad">Schedule Appointment</a></li>
<li class="inactive-link"><a href="/appointment?q=q8345lbf3r9tcmgMnfsad">Schedule Appointment</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you try `.click()`ing it?

Comment: I tried `document.getElementsByClassName("inactive-link")[0].click()` but do not work

Comment: Google chrome console output is `undefined`

Comment: The `.inactive-link` is the `<li>`. If you want to click the `<a>`, you need to select the `<a>`

Comment: How can I do that? I cannot find any good solution

Comment: ok got it now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 <ul>
<li class="inactive-link"><a href="#">Schedule Appointment</a></li>
<li class="inactive-link"><a href="#">Schedule Appointment</a></li>
</ul>
```

The question is pretty unclear regarding what you're trying to achieve but for the js part use

```
 document.querySelector(".inactive-link a").addEventListener('click',()=>{
             window.location="appointment?q=q8345lbf3r9tcmgMnfsad"
    })
```

Adds the click event to the first li>a element (You can add it to all using forEach). This produces an equivalent result.